# variable null en contador php

Tags: php, session, contador

Quiero hacer un contador en php que elimine la sesión `$_SESSION["error"]` si ha pasado un tiempo N. `$_SESSION["error"]` va acumulando los conteos, 1, 2, etc.

El problema es que la primera vez que veo el `echo` devuelto el alert sale en  blanco. La segunda vez que entro veo 1, 2, etc.

No entiendo que esto haciendo mal.

```
$ahora = @date("Y-n-j H:i:s");

$count=$_SESSION["error"];
$_SESSION["error"]=$count+1;

$timeOutError = 10; //Tiempo en segundos

$fechaGuardadaError = $_SESSION["app"]["ultimoAccesoError"];

$tiempoError = (@strtotime($ahora) - @strtotime($fechaGuardadaError));
if ($tiempoError >= $timeOutError){
    unset($_SESSION["error"]);
}

$_SESSION["app"]["ultimoAccesoError"]=$ahora;
echo $_SESSION["error"];
```

Esta es la función desde donde llamo al archivo php, cuando sale del archivo vuelve a la función y es donde compruebo el valor del `echo`.

```
function login(){
    usuario=$('#idUsuario').val(); 
    clave=$('#idClave').val(); 
    var direccion = 'principal.html';
        var parametros = {
            "usuario":usuario,
            "clave":clave,
        }

        $.ajax ({
            data: parametros,
            url: "php/login.php",
            type: "POST",

            success: function(data){
                alert(data); //Aqui veo el echo de php
                if(data==-1){ // Correcto
                    location.href=direccion;
                }
                else if(data>=0&&data<=2){ //Incorrecto
                    intentos= 3-data;
                    $('#idTextoError').html("<center><strong>Identificaci&oacute;n erronea, quedan " +intentos+" Intentos.</strong></center>"); //Error de Usuario/Clave
                    $('#idTextoError').show();
                }
                else if(data>=3){
                    $('#idTextoError').html("<center><strong>Ha superado el numero maximo de intentos. Espere 1 minuto hasta pronximo intento</strong></center>"); //Error de Usuario/Clave
                    $('#idTextoError').show();
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

La forma en la que lo he solucionado es la siguiente:

```
$ahora = @date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
                    if($_SESSION["error"]==0){
                        $fechaGuardadaError=$ahora;
                    }
                    else{
                        $fechaGuardadaError = $_SESSION["app"]["ultimoAccesoError"];
                    }

                    $_SESSION["error"]=$_SESSION["error"] +1;
                    $timeOutError =6; //Tiempo en segundos
                    $tiempoError = (@strtotime($ahora) - @strtotime($fechaGuardadaError));
                    if ($tiempoError > $timeOutError){
                        $_SESSION["error"]=0;
                    }       
                    $_SESSION["app"]["ultimoAccesoError"]=$ahora;
                    openlog("areaPrivada", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL0); 
                    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Login error: Usuario: $usuario, IP: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} "); 
                    closelog(); 
                    echo $_SESSION["error"];
```

Nueva Función Login:

```
usuario=$('#idUsuario').val(); 
    clave=$('#idClave').val(); 
    var direccion = 'principal.html';
        var parametros = {
            "usuario":usuario,
            "clave":clave,
        }

        $.ajax ({
            data: parametros,
            url: "php/login.php",
            type: "POST",

            success: function(data){
            if(data==-1){ // Correcto
                    location.href=direccion;
                }
                else if(data>=0&&data<5){ //Incorrecto
                    intentos= 5-data;
                    $('#idTextoError').html("<center><strong>Identificaci&oacute;n erronea, quedan " +intentos+" Intentos.</strong></center>"); //Error de Usuario/Clave
                    $('#idTextoError').show();
                }
                else if(data>=5){
                    $('#idTextoError').html("<center><strong>Ha superado el numero maximo de intentos. Espere 5 minutos hasta pronximo intento</strong></center>"); //Error de Usuario/Clave
                    $('#idTextoError').show();
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

Comment: Has probado que la primera vez no entre en el if de $tiempoError >= $timeOutError?

Comment: Efectivamente, la primera vez entra en el if....

Comment: Pues al hacer el unset  `$_SESSION["error"]` queda nula y por eso sale en blanco

Comment: En vez de usar `unset` asígnale el valor cero. Y al inicio del script, si quieres que el contador de errores inicie en cero, comprobar si está seteada la llave `error` en $_SESSION y de lo contrario fijarla en cero.